# Fazer com que URL abra na mesma Activity

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-activity, webview

Estou criando uma `WebView` para Android. Quando carrego o App, a página importada funciona perfeitamente, porém quando clico em algum *link* da página, esse mesmo *link* abre em outro navegador.

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer com que todos os *links* abram na mesma `Activity` dessa `WebView`?

Código-fonte:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);


        WebView wv = new WebView(this); //(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        wv.setLayoutParams(lp);

        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setSupportZoom(false);

        wv.loadUrl("http://www.exemplo.com.br/");

        ll.addView(wv);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Defina um WebViewClient na sua WebView para que ele faça o tratamento das URLs:

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado jovem. Funcionou certinho! :D

Comment: Aceite a resposta do Eduardo como correta então...